# WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 not returning user claims in SAML Response

Tags: wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

While trying out the new version of WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 I'm having problems returning claims in the SAML response. While this worked in WSO2 IS 5.0.0 SP1. I've mapped the required claims and added them to my SP, also I configured the SP to always return the user attributes.

I've configured the SP claim mapping:

[image: SP Claim Config]

My SAML configuration:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm getting the feeling this might be a bug.

EDIT: In WSO2 5.1.0 it is required to add the Attribute Consuming Service Index to the SAML Request. In WSO2 5.0.0 SP1 it worked even without setting this value in the SAML Request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you correctly, You can authenticate from IS without any errors, but didn't get claims on SAML response.

I have tried this with Travelocity sample. It is working as expected. I got the user claims in the SAML response. According to the screen shots that you have attached, you have done the configurations correctly. 
Please check & verify that you have values on these mapped claims. If there is no values in user's profile, claims will not be in SAML response. 
You can check this with SSO Tracer or SAML Tracer.

Comment: You're right, I get a success response from WSO2, however no AttributeStatement are added to the SAML response.

I have the claims mapped to certain fields in the database. When I view a user profile from the carbon interface I can see that the claims are indeed mapped to a value.

Comment: As I understand, Still you didn't get the claims in the SAML response though you have added values to the defined claims in user's profile. 
Did you get any errors in WSO2 carbon log?

Or 

Please enable below debug logs on log4j.propertoes file which is under <IS_HOME>/repository/conf directory.

'log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework=DEBUG'

Then do the scenario for one time and send the carbon logs for further analyzing.

Comment: Found it. I forgot to add the Attribute Consuming Service Index to the SAML request. Everything went well with WSO 5.0.0 even without adding this Attribute Consuming Service Index to the SAML request. Apparently it's now required to add this to the Request. Will update the original post with my findings.