# SAML Claims not returned by WSO2 IS 5.1.0

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 5.1 – STS service. With the stsclient (java program) I am making a SAML token request. However, I am not getting the claims details as part of the SAML token response from IS.
The same request is returning the claims when a request is sent to WSO2 IS 5.0. 
For SSO requirement Looks like I have to set  “Attribute Consuming Service Index”. But not sure where to set this attribute in the SAML request while using the stsclient java program.
This resembles [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849993/wso2-identity-server-5-1-0-not-returning-user-claims-in-saml-response) question but not related to STS.

Answer (score 1):

In your Service Provider's SAML configuration, you have to make sure following two checkboxes are checked.

Enable Attribute Profile
 Include Attributes in the Response Always

Then, inside the Claim Configuration section of the Service Provider, you have to add the particular user claims that you wish to receive in SAML response as the Requested Claims.

Then you should be able to receive the user claims in SAML response, provided that user's profile already contains values for these claims.

Refer [1] for more details.

[1] http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2016/08/retrieving-user-claims-in-saml-response.html